# jQuery rearrange images

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery, I have the following HTML:

```
<img id='1' src="1.jpg" />
<img id='2' src="2.jpg" />
<img id='3' src="3.jpg" />
<img id='4' src="4.jpg" />
<img id='5' src="5.jpg" />
```

On my script it was being rearrange like this:

```
<img id='1' src="1.jpg" />
<img id='4' src="4.jpg" />
<img id='2' src="2.jpg" />
<img id='5' src="5.jpg" />
<img id='3' src="3.jpg" />
```

How do I make it go back to proper arrangement?

```
<img id='1' src="1.jpg" />
<img id='2' src="2.jpg" />
<img id='3' src="3.jpg" />
<img id='4' src="4.jpg" />
<img id='5' src="5.jpg" />
```

TIA!!!

Comment: yes... sorry for my bad english...

Comment: I don't really see why you would need to realign it, the code is still exactly the same, just a bit jumbled, if you could be a little more specific though, i could give you a better answer. Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var len = $('img').length;

for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
  $('img[id='+i+']').appendTo('#container')
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v35eX/

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in an array and use the sort function. 
You can read [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) how to write a custom comarator.